# Eclipse DDMS not recognizing my Android phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have opened debug mode on my phone and explorer mounts my phone's disk but I can't see it on DDMS. What should I do?

Comment: Which phone is it? Some phones require specific drivers to be debugged (some HTCs come to mind).

Comment: Have you installed HTC Sync? I believe I needed to install that before I could debug the Aria. Also, i think you need to choose "HTC Sync" in the phone when it asks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have set USB debugging as true.  Connect and set to HTC Sync. On windows environment you will need to install drivers for it.( download from HTC website). On Mac, it automatically takes it up.